# Cómo conectar las credenciales de Wordpress con Localhost Xampp

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress, xampp

Tengo un problema con wordpress instalado en un máquina local, trato de instalar plugins y me pide el Name, User y Password de la Database.
He tratado de usar el nombre de usuario y root, pero igual me arroja como error que no se puede conectar a la Base de Datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola Kike si estas en xampp puedes conocer los detalles de tu conexión a mysql desde el archivo

> config.inc.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

accede a el desde el panel de control de xampp haciendo click en config y luego en phpMyadmin en este archivo encontraras el usuario y contraseña de la conexion mysql

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

copia los datos de las comillas simples y ponlo en su reespectivo lugar.

**recuerda que** deberás crear primero la base de datos en tu servidor mysql antes de instalar worpress, en tu caso deberas crear una BD con el nombre que pongas en *Database name*

> accede a http://localhost/phpmyadmin para crear y administrar tus
> bases de datos

Comment: Gracias Cristián, seguiré tus datos. Gracias!